# Git: unable to resolve differences between master and origin/master

Tags: git, github

I have recently changed my code to be hosted on Github, and have been deploying it onto my live site using:

```
git pull origin master
```

Where origin is set to `https://github.com/myname/myproject`.

Everything works OK, except for git status, which shows:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 74 commits.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

This isn't correct - I haven't made any commits that need publishing. If I try to look at details using `git diff master origin/master`, I can see a large number of files listed. However, I can't see where these changes come from: taking a file that I know well and looking at its history, I can see that the version shown by `git log` is exactly as it should be looking at the version on Github.

Things I have tried which haven't worked:

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

I was expecting this to bring the remote master into my local master. But it had no effect on the status.

```
git reset --hard origin/master
```

This actually broke my site by checking out some other version of the code. I don't know which. I had to do an emergency `git pull origin master` to recover, which (thankfully) got the system back working but left my status in this unstable state.

Can someone help?

By the way, I've now read that using `git pull` as a deployment mechanism is considered dangerous, but I don't really understand why and I haven't found a clearly superior way of doing it in a Github context - I'm open to suggestions!

(updated in response to a comment: here is the response to `git remote show origin`:)

```
* remote origin
  Fetch URL: https://github.com/myname/myproject
  Push  URL: https://github.com/myname/myproject
  HEAD branch: master
  Remote branches:
    fixes8p03 tracked
    fixes8p07 tracked
    master    tracked
    rfc2188   new (next fetch will store in remotes/origin)
  Local branch configured for 'git pull':
    master merges with remote master
  Local ref configured for 'git push':
    master pushes to master (up to date)
```

Comment: The message tells you what to do. - use "git push" to publish your local commits

Comment: I don't why you would have this invisible log. However, I know that some times I have a hard time understanding logs when changing environment (unix to dos for instant) because it messes with file permissions. Maybe this will help you? :)

Comment: Maybe also check `git remote show origin` for any oddities? Some element could be off in your config.

Comment: Using `git log`, check what commits you see on your production server :

    `git log --oneline --graph master origin/master`

Comment: @evolutionxbox: so I have correct code in origin/master, correct code in my working tree, and what the system is telling me is incorrect code in my local master. Surely pushing the supposedly incorrect code is the last thing I want to do right now?

Comment: Why do you assume your local master is incorrect? Git isn't saying you have anything incorrect. It is letting you know that your local master branch is pointing to a commit which is 75 ahead of the one on origin.

Comment: Just do the push!

Comment: Which version of git are you using on the machine where you are deploying? (`git --version` to check) I have an idea of what might be going on - potentially it's completely innocuous.

Comment: The git version is 1.8.3.1, running on Centos 7

Answer (score 1):

Your remote `origin/master` branch didn't get updated and fell behind the local `master` branch. They haven't diverged but the remote branch is 74 commits behind the local one. You have two options:

If the new changes in the local branch are made on purpose, just push them to `origin/master`:

`git push origin master`

If you don't want the changes for any reason, you can reset your `master` branch to its remote state. That means you overwrite `master` with `origin/master`. **Attention, you will lose all the 74 changes that you committed before**:

`git reset --hard origin/master`

Comment: They haven't diverged though. The local branch is simply ahead of the origin branch it seems.

Comment: Actually, I think Deniz is right: they have diverged, and I don't know why. Here's the thing: the code in origin/master and in my checked-out version are the same, and are correct. But the code in the local master is wrong. So I don't dare do a git push, and when I tried "git reset --hard", I ended up with the *wrong* version of code in my checked out version.

Comment: So truth resides only on the server? Then delete the local working folder and check out a new working folder from the server.

Comment: matt: Snce this is my live site, I can't do it without user disruption, that I was trying to avoid. But you're right: if nothing else works, that's what I'll have to do. I can probably keep downtime down to a couple of minutes.